# Using temp tables in pyspark queries

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to read some data into Spark using SQL. The query, for performance reasons, really requires a temp table. When I try and use a query including a temp table as outlined below however spark insists that there is a syntax error, even though that's not true.

For example, this works fine:

```
# pre-emptive stuff that loads connection parameters and whatnot

query = """
select top 50
  *
from DW.Dim.Sales
"""

df = spark.read\
    .format("jdbc")\
    .option("url", url)\
    .option("query", query)\
    .option("user", 'svcDataBricks_DEV')\
    .option("password", sql_password)\
    .load()
```

But this returns an error:

```
query = """
select top 50
  *
into #MyData
from DW.Dim.Sales
"""

df = spark.read\
    .format("jdbc")\
    .option("url", url)\
    .option("query", query)\
    .option("user", 'svcDataBricks_DEV')\
    .option("password", sql_password)\
    .load()
```

Specifically this error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'into'.

I guess the problem is that `spark.read()` is not designed to do any kind of write action, but the documentation is somewhat opaque so I can't quite discern how to make this work.

Comment: You can create a temp table in Spark? Is there specific reason you want to create the temp table in SQL server?

Comment: @jjayadeep Because the query requires quite a lot of aggregation of data to be joined into the main table; running that aggregation as a view is really slow. Running it as a temp table and adding appropriate indices makes it much more performant.

Answer (score 0):

[See my answer over in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70902845/530545).

In short, it's not working because the driver is prepending your Sql with`SELECT * FROM (` and appending it with `) spark_generated_alias`. That makes what you wrote syntactically incorrect. You have to get creative with your own custom "Sql injection attack" to get what you want.