# Spark JDBC SQL connector "SELECT INTO" Statement

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to read the data from SQL Server. Because of some requirements I need to create a temp table using `SELECT INTO` statement, that will be used further in the query. But when I run the query I get the following error

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'

My question is, is the `SELECT INTO` statement allowed with Spark SQL Connector?

Here is a sample query and code

```
    drivers = {"mssql": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"}
    sparkDf = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", connectionString) \
        .option("query", "SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM Table1") \
        .option("user", username) \
        .option("password", password) \
        .option("driver",  "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
        .load()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the driver is doing extra stuff which is getting in your way. More explicitly, the problem is [documented here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html). Here's docs from that page for the "query" option you're using:

> A query that will be used to read data into Spark. The specified query
> will be parenthesized and used as a subquery in the FROM clause. Spark
> will also assign an alias to the subquery clause. As an example, spark
> will issue a query of the following form to the JDBC Source.
>
> SELECT  FROM (<user_specified_query>) spark_gen_alias
>
> Below are a couple of restrictions while using this option.
>
> ```
> It is not allowed to specify dbtable and query options at the same time.
> It is not allowed to specify query and partitionColumn options at the same time. When specifying partitionColumn option is required, the
> ```
>
> subquery can be specified using dbtable option instead and partition
> columns can be qualified using the subquery alias provided as part of
> dbtable.
> Example:
> spark.read.format("jdbc")
> .option("url", jdbcUrl)
> .option("query", "select c1, c2 from t1")
> .load()

Essentially, that wrapper that the driver is putting around your code is causing the problem. And because their wrapper starts with `SELECT * FROM (` and ends with `) spark_generated_alias`, you're very limited in how you can "break out" of it and still execute the statements you want.

### Here's how I do it.

I break it into 3 separate queries, because normal (#) and global (##) temp-tables don't work (the driver disconnects after each query).

Query 1:

```
SELECT 1 AS col) AS tbl; --terminates the "SELECT * FROM (" the driver prepends

--Write whatever Sql you want, then select into a new "real" table.
--E.g. here's your example, but with a "real" table.
SELECT * INTO _TempTable FROM Table1;

SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT 1 AS col --and the driver will append ") spark_generated_alias". The driver ignores all result-sets but the first.
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM _TempTable;
```

Query 3 (you cannot run this until after you're done with the DataFrame):

```
SELECT 1 AS col) AS tbl; --terminates the "SELECT * FROM (" the driver prepends

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _TempTable;

SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT 1 AS col --and the driver will append ") spark_generated_alias". The driver ignores all result-sets but the first.
```